# Polymer: two gulp errors at build time: 'async completion' and 'apply' property

Tags: gulp, polymer

[I'm trying to run `gulp` to build my app like Rob Dodson explains here](https://youtu.be/ByV3MWTa1fw?list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN&t=8m56s).

#### Original error

At the command line, if I run:

```
npm run build
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> [20:50:55] Using gulpfile ~/path/to/gulpfile.js
> [20:50:55] Starting 'default'...
> Deleting build/ directory...
> [20:50:56] The following tasks did not complete: default
> [20:50:56] Did you forget to signal async completion?
> ```

It appears there is some task described as "*signal async completion*?" What does this mean? And how do I do it?

#### Alternate error

However if I run the following at the command line:

```
gulp
```

I get a different error message as follows:

> ```
> [23:40:57] Using gulpfile ~/path/to/gulpfile.js
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129
>     gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
>                   ^
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
>     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:19
>     at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
>     at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
>     at startup (node.js:139:18)
>     at node.js:968:3
> ```

Why would there be different error messages? Does that give a hint what's actually causing the errors? If so, what is it? And what can I do to fix it?

#### My code

[I just copied the files *package.json*, *polymer.json* and *gulpfile.js* from the sample code Rob supplied here](https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/tree/master/ep60-firebase-build). Then I ran `npm install` [as this answer describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775803/1640892).

gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

// Documentation on what goes into PolymerProject.
const path = require('path');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const mergeStream = require('merge-stream');
const del = require('del');
const polymerJsonPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'polymer.json');
const polymerJSON = require(polymerJsonPath);
const polymer = require('polymer-build');
const polymerProject = new polymer.PolymerProject(polymerJSON);
const buildDirectory = 'build/bundled';

/**
 * Waits for the given ReadableStream
 */
function waitFor(stream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.on('end', resolve);
    stream.on('error', reject);
  });
}

function build() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Okay, so first thing we do is clear the build
    console.log(`Deleting build/ directory...`);
    del([buildDirectory])
      .then(_ => {
        // Okay, now lets get your source files
        let sourcesStream = polymerProject.sources()
          // Oh, well do you want to minify stuff? Go for it! 
          // Here's how splitHtml & gulpif work
          .pipe(polymerProject.splitHtml())
            .pipe(gulpif(/\.js$/, uglify()))
            .pipe(gulpif(/\.css$/, cssSlam()))
            .pipe(gulpif(/\.html$/, htmlMinifier()))
          .pipe(polymerProject.rejoinHtml());

        // Okay now lets do the same to your dependencies
        let depsStream = polymerProject.dependencies()
          .pipe(polymerProject.splitHtml())
            .pipe(gulpif(/\.js$/, uglify()))
            .pipe(gulpif(/\.css$/, cssSlam()))
            .pipe(gulpif(/\.html$/, htmlMinifier()))
          .pipe(polymerProject.rejoinHtml());

        // Okay, now lets merge them into a single build stream.
        let buildStream = mergeStream(sourcesStream, depsStream)
          .once('data', () => {
            console.log('Analyzing build dependencies...');
          });

        // If you want bundling, do some bundling! Explain why?
        buildStream = buildStream.pipe(polymerProject.bundler);

        // If you want to add prefetch links, do it! Explain why?
        // buildStream = buildStream.pipe(new PrefetchTransform(polymerProject));

        // Okay, time to pipe to the build directory
        buildStream = buildStream.pipe(gulp.dest(buildDirectory));

        // waitFor the buildStream to complete
        return waitFor(buildStream);
      })
      .then(_ => {
        // You did it!
        console.log('Build complete!');
        resolve();
      });
  });
}

gulp.task('default', build);
```

Comment: Found this which seems to hint at an issue with gulp and del: https://github.com/sindresorhus/del/issues/45

Comment: The problem is not necessarily `del`. The console log shows `"Deleting build/ directory"`, which `build()` *always* prints, so the problem could be anywhere after that point. It's often seen when one of the Gulp streams silently fails (does not emit an `error` event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original error is unrelated to the "alternate error".

While the [`build` task runs `gulp`](https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/blob/353c8de/ep60-firebase-build/package.json#L6), `npm run` prioritizes the locally-installed `gulp` (at `node_modules/.bin/gulp`) before the system-installed `gulp`. Running `gulp` yourself (without `npm run`) would invoke the globally-installed `gulp`, which may result in an error if it's incompatible with your project (e.g., Gulp 3 binary with Gulp 4 API in your scripts, which appears to be the case). You could either install Gulp 4 so that you can run `gulp` yourself, or continue using `npm run build`.

To troubleshoot the original error, I recommend starting from the [Polycast's original source](https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/tree/353c8de/ep60-firebase-build) (if you haven't already) to determine what the difference could be.

If you prefer to stick with your current track, I suggest a few things:

- Verify the paths in your HTML imports, as a path to a non-existent file would cause a silent error ([`polymer-build` issue 88](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-build/issues/88)). It might be helpful to run `polymer build -v` (verbose build).
- Add `buildStream.on('error', (err) => console.log(err))` after `let buildStream = ...` in case any unsuppressed `error` events crop up in that stream.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the new version of PSK Custom Build:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/generator-polymer-init-custom-build/

It has the `gulpfile.js` updated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by an incorrect import path.

incorrect path

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

correct path

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

As @tony19, correctly described, that errant import path caused a silent failure.

I found this by pursuing the path suggested by @abdonrd. [I followed the instructions here as follows](https://github.com/PolymerElements/generator-polymer-init-custom-build/).

First, I copied my project. Then I loaded into the `my-app` directory per the below described procedure.

https://github.com/PolymerElements/generator-polymer-init-custom-build/

```
npm install -g polymer-cli
npm install -g generator-polymer-init-custom-build
mkdir my-app
cd my-app
polymer init custom-build
polymer build -v  # the results of this command highlighted my error in red
```

The error showed the path of the missing file. Which I noticed was located one level higher than it should have been because the root directory `my-app/` was missing from the path. Then I had to search manually through all the files using the search string `polymer/polymer.html` until I found a mismatch between the number of `../` in the import path (3 in this case) and the number of folders deep into the root directory the importing file was (2 in this case).

After I corrected the file path, I again ran:

```
polymer build -v  # building the project again, correctly this time
polymer serve build/bundled  # to test serve the build/bundled version
```